# Adding files with non .so extension to an APK lib folder

Tags: android, file, gradle, java-native-interface, apk

I would like to add some files with custom extensions to the lib folder of my APK but the build mechanism seems to filter out any file that doesn't have the .so extension.  Is it possible to remove that restriction?

My current gradle file has the following task:

```
task test1()  {
    file("src/main/jniLibs/arm64-v8a/test1.SO").text = "abc"
    file("src/main/jniLibs/arm64-v8a/test2.so").text = "def"
    file("src/main/jniLibs/arm64-v8a/test3.abc").text = "ghi"
    file("src/main/jniLibs/arm64-v8a/test4.bin").text = "jkl"
}


project.afterEvaluate {
    preBuild.dependsOn  test1
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "jni", include: ["*.*"])
...
}
```

This successfully create all four test files under `src/main/jniLibs.arm64-v8a/` but only `test2.so` is then packaged in the APK under lib/arm64-v8a.  How can I have `test3.abc` present in there as well for example?

Comment: Maybe it is stupid question, but ```lib``` folder for libraries, isn't it? Why you don't use for example resources for that (```app/src/main/res/raw/```) or internal or external storages?

Comment: Not a silly question... The runtime environment I use needs specific non-library files to be at the same location as the libraries to work properly.

Comment: Ok, I understand this, but I'm afraid there is nothing to be done about it, because in your case, it seems that changes are required to the APK installer and not only workaround during build.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to solve exactly this problem so that my system app can have a native executable that can be actually executed (SELinux rules will not allow that under `getFilesDir()`). My first workaround was to simply add the `.so` file extension to my executable, but I didn't like that.

The final solution was to place my files under `MyProject/app/src/main/resources/lib/arm64-v8a/`. This way they get extracted into the path returned by `getApplicationInfo().nativeLibraryDir` (and yes, they can be executed as well).